# Single quote expansion within an array

Tags: bash, quoting

AFAICT, anything inside a single quotes shouldn't be expanded. Bash manual says:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of 
>   each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur 
>   between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

However, in an older bash version this doesn't appear to be true in Bash `3.00.15(1)-release`.

For example, consider (this is a contrived example of a bigger script):

```
#!/bin/bash

func() {
local -a cmds=('echo subshell echo hi')

    for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
        echo "cmd: $cmd"
    done
}

func
```

prints:

```
cmd: echo
cmd: subshell
cmd: echo
cmd: hi
```

whereas I expected:

```
cmd: echo subshell echo hi
```

This is not an issue in newer bash versions. The above works as expected in Bash `3.2.25(1)-release` and `4.3.46(1)-release`.

Is this a bug in older bash shells? How can work around it so that single quoting preserves values (as I expected above) in bash `3.00.15(1)-release`?

Comment: Why do you have to support such an old bash version? Even OS X, which hasn't updated its bash in years, has 3.2.57.

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug. What does `echo ${#cmds[@]}` show?

Comment: I don't think SO is the right place for a 10 year old bug report. The workaround is to assign the elements one by one, like `cmds[0]='foo bar'` and so on. And btw, upgrade the shell...

Comment: @hek2mgl That workaround assumes that it is the assignment that causes the problem, not the expansion.

Comment: That version is not even patched for the ShellShock bug. If for some reason you must support 3.0.x, at least patch it to 3.00.22.

Comment: @chepner I admit that I didn't tried it, but it makes sense for me. (Why should any, broken, parser make $cmd[0] => 'foo' and $cmd[1] => 'bar' out of `$cmd[0]='foo bar'?) I guessed that the problem lies in parsing the array=(...) assignment, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I agree it was more likely (easy to say in hindsight, after I compiled a 3.00 shell), but there are enough expansion-related bugs in older versions that I thought it plausible that `${cmds[@]}` could be to blame.

Comment: I see. Good research btw...

Comment: @hek2mgl, I think SO *is* the perfect place to ask a question like this. (And this particular question is very well asked.) This isn't a bash bug report, it's a request for help to program something in a shell dialect that perhaps isn't so common anymore. It's not always practical or even possible to upgrade to the latest version, or at all. Embedded systems with software copied from ROM, satellites in orbit, etc, might very well be stuck in an un-upgradeable state.

Comment: @ghoti I don't see the problem. Send some astronauts out there, reflash the ROM with a new bash, job done. Probably they could also empty /var/log when they are already there.

Comment: That's one of the oldest version of Bash (works on all others -- which are newer) I have to support and if upgrading was an option I wouldn't have asked for help (since I know it works at least since 3.2.25).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in `bash` 3.00.16 (the closest I could compile without manually patching 3.00), the bug appears to be related including the assignment in the `local` command. The following produces the expected output:

```
func() {
    local -a cmds
    cmds=('echo subshell echo hi')

    for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
        echo "cmd: $cmd"
    done
}

func
```

This isn't specific to `local`; it appears to be a problem with processing assignments that appear as arguments.

```
bash-3.00$ declare -a foo=('echo bar')
bash-3.00$ printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"
echo
bar
bash-3.00$ foo=('echo bar')
bash-3.00$ printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"
echo bar
```